# CMake how to set the correct inclusion path prefix on VC2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, opencv, cmake

So basically i am using cmake to create project for visual studio 2010 with opencv.

I have followed this guide on windows 7 and all worked fine: http://redkiing.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/opencv-and-visual-studio-2010-with-cmake/

Then i have tried it with windows vista and cmake keeps creating the project with bad inclusion directory resulting in the error: `C:\Program Files\OpenCV\include\opencv\cv.h(63): fatal error "opencv2/core/core_c.h" no such file or directory`

Cmake instead to set the correct dir like this

```
C:\Program Files\OpenCV/modules/core/include
etc
```

It sets that directroy like this: (and they dont' exist):

```
C:\Program Files\myFirstOpenCVProject\Files/modules/core/include
```

I had to include manually all the correct path. Is there any way to tell cmake which are the correct path?

Cmake version 2.8.8

### Edit

Cmake file i am using:

```
SET( PROJECT_NAME project_name_goes_here )
PROJECT( ${PROJECT_NAME} )
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
ADD_EXECUTABLE( ${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Comment: Is it `Progam Files` or `Program Files`?!

Comment: I am not clear on your question - are you trying to build opencv? or are you having trouble including OpenCV files in your Visual Studio project?

Comment: I am doing a project that needs OpenCV. But all inclusion dir setted by cmake are wrong. Basically it's the 4th step of: http://redkiing.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/opencv-and-visual-studio-2010-with-cmake/

Comment: How are you adding the include path of OpenCV? In the 4th step of the link you gave, the CMakeList.txt sample DOES NOT include the OpenCV include directory as far as I could tell.

Comment: @Lap: hm, how/where can I specify that directory ? That is what I am really looking for :) !

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure how the FindOpenCV.cmake module is setup, but I think you need to add the line:

```
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Before the `add_executable` line.

**Edit:** I assume you're using this [FindOpenCV.cmake](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FindOpenCV.cmake)

Comment: I have downloaded opencv trunk and then created the project with cmake, i followed this: http://redkiing.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/opencv-and-visual-studio-2010-with-cmake/

Comment: Looking at the tutorial, the author definitely missed the detail on how to set up the include paths in his CMake setup.

Comment: on windows 7 it works fine, cmake already sets the good include directory. But when i tried it on vista it didn't work. Anyway I haven't tried yet your solution i will let you know !

Comment: sorry for late answer, anyway your solution isn't working. CMake still makes the solution with wrong paths